# How to use 'useState' to change the value of <input> in React?

Tags: reactjs

I made an app with React that has a search box that displays suggestions to the users as they type. Now I would like to make these suggestions clickable, so  when the user clicks on one of them, it will replace the value of the search box.

The input component is:

```
export function Search(){
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")

   const handleInput = (event) => {
       setInputValue(event.target.value)
   } 

   return(
       <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleInput}/>
       <Suggestions mySuggestions={mySuggestions} setInputValue={setInputValue} />
   )
}
```

And the suggestions component is:

```
export function Suggestions({setInputValue}){

      return (
         <div className="suggestions">
            <ul>
               {mySuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                  const {meaning} = suggestion._source
                  return <li onClick={()=> setInputValue({meaning})} key={index}>{meaning}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
         </div>
        )
    }

};
```

The 'setInputValue' is working properly in the first component as the value updates as I type, but in the second component, it isn't working. The suggestions are displayed, but when I click on them, the value doesn't update.

Does anyone know what is the problem with my code?

Update:

I tried removing the curly braces from `onClick={()=> setInputValue({meaning})}`, but it still didn't work. I tried `onClick={()=> setInputValue(meaning)}`.

Comment: Given this line: `const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")` your state is a string, though later you update it with an object: `onClick={()=> setInputValue({meaning})}`. You need to decide what you want, because it can't be both. I would expect it to be: ``onClick={()=> setInputValue(meaning)}``

Comment: I removed the curly braces, but it still didn't work. But thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a curly brace in Suggestions()

```
export function Suggestions({ setInputValue }) {
  return (
    <div className="suggestions">
      <ul>
        {mySuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
          const { meaning } = suggestion._source;
          return (
            <li onClick={() => setInputValue(meaning)} key={index}>
              {meaning}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo in the entry. There is this curly brace in my code. I already corrected the entry.

Comment: There was one extra curly braces inside  setInputValue as well,

Comment: I tried removing them, but it still didn't work. Is there anything else that could be causing the problem?

Comment: The code I posted is working in my system, may be you can create a codesandbox and show

Comment: I am new at Stackoverflow. I still don't know how to create a codesandbox. I will search about it.

Comment: reproduce the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-zhukovsky-wwkgb?file=/src/App.js)